# Lebesgue Measure, why is this continuous from above?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Define the sets: $$E_n=\left(\bigcup_i(q_i-1/n,q_i+1/n)\right)\bigcap[0,1]\;\;,i \in \mathbb{N}$$

where $q_i$ are enumerations of rational numbers.

Clearly, $$\lim\mu(E_i)=1$$ but $$\mu\left(\bigcap_nE_n \right)=0\;\;,n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Where $\mu$ is lebesgue measure. So this is not continuous from above.

Where is the mistake in my assumption?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, by density of the rationals, $E_n=[0,1]$ for each $n$.

Comment: could you elaborate, why $\mu(A_{k2^k})\leqslant \frac 1k$ follows from subaditivity?

Comment: @d.a. Sorry, I misred the definition of $A_k$.

Comment: yes, the fact that $E_n=[0,1]$ is necessary, but is not $$\bigcap\left(\left(\bigcup_i(q_i-1/n,q_i+1/n)\right)\bigcap[0,1]\;\;,i \in \mathbb{N}\right)=\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$$? where intersection is countable intersection over all $n$. I get it now but it's quiet unintuitive when you consider this as similar intersections of sets like $(1+1/n,0)$. Thanks.